# Prove that the quotient ring $R/(f)$ has four elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[t]$, $f=t^2+t+1$. Show that $R/(f)$ has four elements.

So I know that $R/(f)$ has the form $\lbrace a+(f) \mid a \in R \rbrace$, and $(f)$ is the ideal generated by $f$. How do I see that $R/(f)$ only has four elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you can say $R/(f)$ is exactly the set $\{a+(f)\mid \deg(a) < \deg(f)\}$ since if $\deg(a)\geq \deg(f)$, then there exists $q$ and $r$ such that $a=qf+r$ where $\deg(r)<\deg(f)$ and so $a+(f)=qf+r+(f)=r+(f)$. Therefore if $F$ is a finite field with $q$ elements and $f\in F[x]$ has degree $n$, we can deduce that $|F[x]/(f)|=q^{n}$.

Comment: So explicitly $R/(f)= \lbrace 0+(f),1+(f),t+(f),t+1+(f) \rbrace$, right?

Comment: Exactly @Lewis .